# MongoDB extract numeric data

Tags: mongodb

I have this data in my collection:

```
{"IDF": "P-1234"
"Name": "Jonh"}
```

And I would like to get the IDF that the numeric part is pair. I tried with that code but it doesn't work.

```
db.getCollection('Users').find({($substr:['IDF',2,6]):{$mod:[2,0]}})
```

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: I want a list of users because there is another metric: "Name" which is the name of the users.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.getCollection('Users').aggregate([
{"$addFields":{"new":{$substr:["$IDF",2,6]}}},
{"$addFields":{"IDFNum":{"$toDouble":"$new"},

}},
{ "$addFields": { "remainder": { "$mod": [ "$IDFNum", 2 ] } } },
{"$match":{"remainder":{"$eq":0}}}
]
)
```